# Raspberry Pi 4 No IP assigned to network interface

Tags: linux, network-interface, internet

After a dist-upgrade + reboot I couldn't access my Raspberry Pi via the network.
After some time digging I found out that it has no IP assigned via `ifconfig`.
I was able to successfully assign an IP with  `sudo ifconfig x.x.x.x` but this is not what I want after every reboot.

In my `/etc/network/interfaces` config file the interface is configured with a static IP and did always work. When booting up I did see an error from the `dhcpcd` service which says `dhcpcd failed to start`. Someone on a forum said that you could disable this service if you don't use DHCP, so I did.

B.T.W because I have no network access it is very hard to copy some data/logs because I'm only connected via HDMI.

Pastebin of the /var/log/syslog [link](https://pastebin.com/6YZU13Y1)

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.178.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.178.1
```

My question is does someone know why the IP from `/etc/network/interfaces` is not automatically assigned? And how can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boot up the RasPi. Check from the logs under `/var/log/` which ones contain relevant messages. Connect a USB stick to the RasPi, copy the relevant logs on the stick and you can upload them to Pastebin, then [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738406/edit) your question to add links.

Comment: FWIW, it's not a Raspberry Pi OS, but an Ubuntu (probably 20.04 LTS) with a kernel for raspi. I guess the next step will be to provide the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` and if anything also `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*`. I'm not sure by what this content is managed (ifupdown? NetworkManager?  systemd-networkd (though it doesn't appear to do anything but discovery) ?)

Comment: 22.04 and NetworkManager :-) You run this with the official PSU, yes? The log suggests this isn't necessarily a stable system. Mine was all kinds of unstable until I bought a 65W PSU for it. I'd suggest 1) unplug all the USB devices except for kbd 2) disable IPv6 3) re-enable `dhcpcd` - I assume you have a DHCP server this can connect to 4) ensure only LAN or Wi-Fi is available for connection. Then reboot, what happens? There are quite a few issues like Apache failing to start, issues with Samba and Docker... best way to troubleshoot is disabling all but basic functionality before starting.

Comment: BTW as you're running quite a lot of stuff on this, have a peek at [DietPi](https://dietpi.com/). A LOT easier on the resources than even Raspi OS Lite, let alone full-blown Ubuntu. Debian-based so not entirely unfamiliar for a Ubuntu user :-)

Comment: Maybe the upgrade removed for unknown reasons the ifupdown (or ifupdown2) package and then nothing claims this configuration? Btw, for a proper answer to be possible the relevant pastebin parts should be included in the question itself. The 2nd link is just a few lines.

Comment: @A.B i did edit the post with the interfaces in the post. BTW /etc/network/interfaces.d/* does not exist. Also i don't know how the content is managed.

Comment: There are too many possibilities for your case. Are you sure doing data backup and reinstalling is not simpler?

Comment: @A.B is there a way to back up all my data so even configuration files from certain programs are kept?

Comment: Looks this appears to be difficult for you too, so I guess no(t simply).

Comment: @A.B Thank you for your help. I did fix it. I mentioned that i could configure my interface via ifconfig. Yes i could access the PI via SSH but later on i discovered that i don't got external access. I could't ping 8.8.8.8 so i did reconfigure my route and voila i got external access. At the end i executed an apt-get upgrade and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I did fix it. I mentioned that i could configure my interface via ifconfig. Yes i could access the PI via SSH but later on i discovered that i don't got external access to the internet. I could't ping 8.8.8.8 so i did reconfigure my route and voila i got external access. At the end i executed an apt-get upgrade and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Excellent :-) Please don't forget to drop back after 48 hours to accept your answer, so this doesn't reappear half a year from now as "Unanswered". I still recommend considering a stronger PSU. And taking a look at DietPi - I'm in no way, shape or form affiliated :-D

Comment: @Peregrino69 yes i will mark it as answered. The psu that i did use was only for debugging. The one i'm using now is fine. Thank you very much for your help.